# React native: characters above text line (for chords above the lyrics)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styles, chord

Is it possible to "put" (style) a character above other character/string in Text component
**without use WebView**?
(for chords above the lyrics)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better you use a special font for music chores, something like this will be great
http://www.jazzfont.com/noframes/cordchar.htm